# VB.Net, keep shift pressed, and release after certain function is done?

Tags: vb.net, shift

Is that possible?

I want to keep my shift pressed in an external application (such as fire fox)
and release it as I pressed it again,
I want it working just like the caps button.

to make it easier to understand,
maybe something like

shift is pressed
Keys.Shift.hold = true

and

shift is pressed again
Keys.shift.hold = false

Answer (score 1):

Apologies in advance for the pseudocode; I don't know VB.net. If you're comfortable with C++, you can adapt code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532119/c-generating-key-combinations-winapi-without-mfc), which I used as a reference.

You can use the [SendInput Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx). According to the function's description, it

> Synthesizes keystrokes, mouse motions, and button clicks.

You *will* need to ensure your target program has a lower process integrity than yours - in other words, if your process isn't running as admin, don't try to feed events to an admin-level process - but since you mentioned Firefox I don't expect this to be an issue for you.

You'll want to set up a [`KEYBDINPUT` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646271(v=vs.85).aspx) like this:

```
wVk = VK_SHIFT
dwFlags = 0 (this will press a key. You'll want KEYEVENTF_KEYUP instead for releasing it.)
```

Then, set up an [`INPUT` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx) like this:

```
type = INPUT_KEYBOARD
ki = yourKeybdInputStruct
```

Now pass that whole `INPUT` structure to `SendInput`:

```
SendInput(1, &yourInputStruct, sizeof(yourInputStruct))
```

---

Alternately, you could try using the VB.net [`SendKeys` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx). There are some caveats that come with this class; most notably,

> If your application is intended for international use with a variety of keyboards, the use of Send could yield unpredictable results and should be avoided.

Additionally, the official documentation says nothing about using a modifier key (Shift, Ctrl, Alt) by itself, nor does it appear to support holding a key down in the manner you describe, just sending a regular keystroke (keydown-keyup).

However, if you're willing to deal with those issues, this might work:

```
SendKeys.Send("+")
```

Comment: Is this the simplest explanations on this? I feel like to cry XD

Comment: @Kaozty This is, as far as I'm aware, the simplest solution to do exactly what you're looking for. I've added an alternate method you could try, but there are serious issues with this imho, and I would strongly recommend using the `SendInput` API as I initially suggested.

Comment: Since .NET 3.0, `SendKeys` actually uses `SendInput`. So whatever caveats apply to `SendKeys` would also apply to `SendInput`. It probably isn't worth P/Invoking everything you need to use `SendInput` just for simple use cases. And yes, the plus sign is the special signal for the Shift key.